# MySQL/PHP Project

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MYSQL database set up through phpmyadmin and connected through PHP. What I want to do next is when I select a player from the dropdown box, I want its value in my field column ( which is not actually displayed when I run my program) to change from 1 to 0 so that the player will not show up again until I run my program again.

Also, how would I be able to display the players that have already been selected in a separate table beside the table that I already have displayed of all the non-selected players?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Seth Rataiczak -->
<head>
        <title>PHP Project</title>
        <style>
            table,th,td {
                border: 1px solid navy;
                }
        </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    $db_hostname='localhost';
    $db_username='root';
    $db_password='';
    $db_database='Project';

    $connection = new mysqli(   $db_hostname,
                                $db_username,
                                $db_password,
                                $db_database);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM NFL_2014_Receiving WHERE Field=1";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if (!$result) die ($connection->error);
        $n = $result->num_rows;   

        $nfl = array();

        echo "<table>
            <tr><th>ID</th><th>Player</th><th>Team</th>
            <th>Position</th><th>Receptions</th>
            <th>Receiving Yards</th><th>Avg Yds/Catch</th>
            <th>Avg Yds/Game</th><th>Touchdowns</th></tr>";

        for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) {
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $nfl[$row['iD']] = $row['Player'];
            if(!isset($_POST['hide']) || $_POST['hide'] != $row['iD']){
                echo "<tr><td width=20>" . $row['iD'] . "</td><td width=150>" . $row['Player'] . "</td><td width=40>" .
                        $row['Team'] . "</td><td width=30>" . $row['Pos'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                        $row['Rec'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds'] . "</td><td width=30>" .
                        $row['Avg'] . "</td><td width=40>" . $row['Yds/G'] . "</td><td width=20>" .
                        $row['TD'] . "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table><br>";

        echo "<form method='post' action=''><select name='hide'>";
        foreach($nfl as $key=>$value){
            echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
        echo "</select></form>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question, but you are printing your input submit inside your select box.

Comment: are you planning on pinging the database or performing a page refresh when you select the player?  The easy thing to do would be to put a view on that table that only returns active players.  However, this is pointless on an easy query.

Comment: ok so currently i am displaying a database that contains a list of NFL receivers and their 2014 stats. Whenever I select one from a dropdown box that name is hidden. However if i select another player, the player originally selected is put back into the table. Therefore i have created a column called Field (not displayed but still there). Everyones value is set to 1 in this field, but when selected i want there value to be 0 so they will not be displayed anymore until i run the program again. Does that make sense?

Comment: you could use jquery hide()Show() function on click method.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side code, so the only way to change the HTML is with javascript and hiding and showing div's or changing text. The reason you have to refresh the page to see your result is because that is only executed on page load.